# TypeError: response.map is not a function - how to fix it?

Tags: postman

Im trying to extract the "restaurant_id" info from one GEt APi and use it in another whats the best way to do it?

```json
"results": [
        {
            "restaurant_url": "https://www.ubereats.com/store/mcdonalds-high-street/7x4Qp__yQFiIzGa2UlqSsQ?diningMode=DELIVERY",
            "restaurant_name": "McDonald's® - High Street",
            "restaurant_id": "ef1e10a7-fff2-4058-88cc-66b6525a92b1",
            "zipcode": "wd19",
            "city": "Watford",
            "cuisine_type": null,
            "star_rating": "3.7",
            "no_of_rating": "200+",
            "latitude": 51.6541,
            "longitude": -0.3942,
            "delivery_time": "10–20 min",
            "opening_hours": null,
            "fulfilled_delivery": false,
            "platform": "UberEats",
            "timestamp": "2022-12-26T16:33:53.234792"
        },
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wuvgX-egdc

[image: 1]

tried this but always getting the error

`TypeError: response.map is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

The correct code would be:

```js
const ids = response.results.map(e -> e.restaurant_id)
```